# Not a decade, but a term for a 9 year span

Tags: single-word-requests, latin

Thanks for the help in advance; first time posting here.

I'm curious what the most appropriate single word is to describe a 9 year time span, or a 9 year anniversary. A search on Google didn't turn up much, but it did help me find this information in the Wiki page for "decade": "*...Other words for spans of years also come from Latin: biennium (2 years), triennium (3 years), quadrennium (4 years), lustrum (5 years)*".

Following this pattern, the most appropriate form of the word I could come up with is **novemnium**, seeing as *novem* is Latin for 9. Is this the correct structure/spelling, or are there better alternatives to this problem?

Comment: Google Books does seem to have _some_ records of 'novemnium', but maybe these are just errors and actually say 'novem nium' (nine ends)https://www.google.co.uk/search?tbm=bks&hl=en&q=novemnium

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The noun form of user's answer (novennial), and I believe you are looking for a noun, is **novennium**

> (rare) A nine-year period or cycle.

[From Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/novennium)

Also see **enneatic**:

> Occurring once in every nine times, days, years, etc.; every ninth.

[From The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Enneatic)

And finally, **enneaeteric**

> Containing or consisting of nine years: as, an enneaeteric period.

[From Wordnik, in turn from The Century Dictionary](https://www.wordnik.com/words/enneaeteric)

Comment: Ah, I spelled it incorrectly. Thanks! And yes, I was looking for the noun form; I should have specified better.

Answer (score 3):

You had the right idea. Leave out the first "m" an use it as an adjective. The word you are seeking is "**novennial**".

https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Novennial

Comment: I'd upvote this answer if I could, but I'm too new apparently. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score -1):

Because there is no zero year, the first “decade” of AD and the last “decade” of BC only have nine years. Since these are sets of nine years, they should be called Nonades, on the model of Decade. In French, a set of nine objects is called a nonade (though not pronounced with a long A). In English this is called a nonad. For a nine year time period, we should use nonade with a long A.